# Firebase messaging (FCM) sending message with delay or not at all

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have seen several threads regarding the same issue and also issues on github but with no solution. When sending push notification using **Firebase FCM** the notification can **randomly get delayed or not recieved at all**. It seems that the **socket gets closed(?)** and then reopened after a while.

If i turn wifi/cellular data on and off it starts working again. My only guess is that the socket to Firebase gets reopened when turning it on and off.

It is hard to debug with the lack of logs in Firebase FCM but is there any way to keep the socket alive?

**Reciever (React Native)**

```
const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
});
```

**Sender (PHP)**

```
$message = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $reciever_token)->withNotification($notification)->withHighestPossiblePriority()->withData([
    // data here
]);
$messaging->send($message);
```

Similar problem below:

[Github 1](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/307) - [Github 2](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/83)

Comment: FCM doesn't guarantee fast or reliable messages.  It just strives to optimize both. The issue is not with the code you write, the device itself and the FCM infrastructure that has to deal with these devices.

Comment: I can understand that but less than 50% is getting recieved and if that should be considered an acceptable number they should just shutdown the service. As long as the socket remains open everything works.

Comment: FCM delivers hundreds of billions of messages daily, is used by Google's own apps, and is in no danger of being shut down. If you think there is a bug or a problem with the quality of service that is clearly demonstrable, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if you check the links i sent you can see how this is considered a problem for many but they still close the issue :( I have narrowed it down to that it seems the socket being closed after inactivity. Is there really no way to keepalive the socket like in websockets?

Comment: If your question is about your code, [don't link to external repositories](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/more-advice#dont-require-external-and-off-site-resources).  The relevant code needs to be copied into the question and [formatted](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code) so that it's easy to read.  We also need to be able to understand what your observations are and how you debug it.

Comment: Well the problem is not in the code but maybe some optional parameter can be added and that is why i add the code. But i will take that into mind in the next post. I am unable to find any helpful logs in firebase but my guess is that the socket timesout to firebase. But that is just a guess based on the behavior.